# Javascript to load another js file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load another JS file from a JS file.

From my JavaScript file **run.js**, I have the following:

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='my_script.js'></script>");
alert(nImages);
```

In side **my_script.js** I have the following:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
nImages = 6;
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

But I can't seem to get it to alert the `nImages` from **my_script.js** file.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to wait until the JS file is actually loaded (in addition to the "it's not an HTML file" part)?

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'my_script.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';

script.onload = function () {
    alert(nImages);
};

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use HTML inside of your script file.  Your script file my_script.js should have only this in it.

```
nImages = 6;
```

Additional note: you don't need `language="JavaScript"` or the `<!--` or `//-->`.  Those are old conventions not needed for modern browsers (even IE6).  I'd also avoid using `document.write()` in your JS as it has performance implications.  You may want to look at a library such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) which provides a better way to load other JS files in the page.

I also have a [code snippet on Github](https://gist.github.com/817519) inspired by Steve Souders that loads another file via straight JS.

```
var theOtherScript = 'http://example.com/js/script.js';

var el = document.createElement('script');
el.async = false;
el.src = theOtherScript;
el.type = 'text/javascript';

(document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0]||document.body).appendChild(el);
```

This will append the other script to the  element (if it exists) or the  of the page.

Comment: Still won't fix it unfortunately, but that is part of the problem.

Comment: It technically should also be in the head

Comment: @Jay What should be, and why?

Comment: For easily removal the script or replacing it since you have not given it an ID.

Comment: This file is on an external server and can't be changed, is there a way I can remove it when it downloads ?

Comment: @Jay I still don't get what you're trying to say, but ok.

Comment: I can only use JavaScript and I need to get the 'nImages' value from this file which I can't edit: http://www.bom.gov.au/radar/IDR713.T.filenames.js

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files should not have HTML in them. They should consist entirely of Javascript code, `so my_script.js` should contain only:

```
nImages = 6;
```

This still won't work because when you write the new script tag into the document it doesn't run immediately. It is guaranteed that `run.js` finishes running before `my_script.js` starts, so `nImages` is undefined when you alert it and then becomes 6 later. You'll see that this works:

```
document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='my_script.js'></script>");

function call_on_load(){
    alert(nImages);
}
```

If the contents of `my_script.js` are:

```
nImages = 6;
call_on_load();
```

**Edit**

Since you said in a comment that you can not edit `my_script.js` you can do this although it is not nearly as nice a solution:

```
// Force nImages to be undefined
var undefined;
window.nImages = undefined;

document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='my_script.js'></script>");

(function is_loaded(cb){
    if(typeof window.nImages == 'undefined')
        setTimeout(function(){ is_loaded(cb); }, 100);
    else
        cb();
})(function(){
    // This is executed after the script has loaded
    alert(nImages);
});
```

This is not a nice solution, however, since it will continue polling indefinitely if there is an error loading the script.

**EDIT**

You posted in a comment the file you want to include, which has the `<SCRIPT` at the top. This file is useless and you can't do anything about it client side. You'd have to write a server side script to load the file as text in which case you can just parse it for the value you want.